# Is it possible to have two different database properties in a single property file?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I need to have two different database properties in a single property file. The format for property files I have looked up on internet looked like this:

```
    test.jdbc.url      = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
    test.jdbc.driver   = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    test.jdbc.username = root
    test.jdbc.password = pass4root
```

But I want the property file to hold details for two databases so that I can connect to the desired database in my Java class. I haven't tried it yet as I am neither sure how to write code for accessing the second database nor sure whether I can have two databases in the same property file at all. Could anyone please let me know if this is possible?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: In theory yes, so long as the keys were unique.  You would need some way to flag which set of properties to use though

Comment: I am sorry but what keys are you talking about? And how do I set the flag differently for different properties?

Comment: A properties file is made of key value pairs, so long as you don't expect to be able to use `test.jdbc.url` twice, you're good.  How you determine which set of properties you want to use, is up to you.  But now I assume you're passing the properties file to the JDBC driver

Comment: Thank you for the info. Yes, I am planning to send these properties to the JDBC driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create sets by enhancing key names

```
test.jdbc.dev.url      = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dev
test.jdbc.dev.driver   = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
test.jdbc.dev.username = dev1
test.jdbc.dev.password = dev1
test.jdbc.test.url      = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
test.jdbc.test.driver   = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
test.jdbc.test.username = test
test.jdbc.test.password = test
```

Comment: In the file above, you meant 'dev' and 'test' are two different databases right? If so, why can't we write the 'dev' DB related properties as 'dev.jdbc.dev.url' etc. Sorry if my doubt is elementary but I am new to this. Thank you

Comment: You can. You can format your properties the way you want. They're just key/value pairs